# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) [2002]

Tags: linux, mysql

For some reason over night mysql has broken. I tried

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
Starting mysqld:        [ OK ]
```

but it doesn't actually appear to start

```
ps aux |grep mysqld
root      5114  0.0  0.0   6260   804 pts/0    S+   09:50   0:00 grep mysqld
```

/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

socket=/tmp/mysql.sock 

[client]

socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

bind-address=127.0.0.1
log=/var/log/mysqld.log
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.error.log
```

Comment: What is in the log files?

Comment: files are empty

Comment: Also check the usual syslog files such as `/var/log/daemon.log`

Comment: nothing mysql related in that either

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Check your storage is having enough space.

You MySQL data directory is having enough permission -

```
chmod 755 <your mysql data directory path>
```

Restart your mysql and check whether its running fine.